# What's the meaning of chemical potential of photons or phonons?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, phonons, chemical-potential, quantum-statistics

The chemical potential of photons or phonons vanishes due to their particle number not conserved, I don't understand it very well. So can you explain what's the meaning of chemical potential of them and why they vanish!

Answer (score 1):

In a typical thermodynamic system entropy is a function of energy, volume, and number of particles: $S=S(E,V,N)$. The partial derivatives of entropy all have simple meaning:
$$
   T =\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N},\quad
   \frac{P}{T} =\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{E,N},\quad
   \frac{\mu}{T} =-\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{E,V}.
$$
The chemical potential ($\mu$) is zero if entropy does not depend on the number of particles. In this case the equilibriums state of the system is independent of the number of photons and is a function of only temperature and pressure.